# how to remove the extra fields in fire checkout 2,7?

Tags: onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

how to remove the extra fields in fire checkout 2,7?
[image]

Comment: Counter question: how did they get there? And what are they even? Most people here cannot read Greek.

Comment: Seem you're using a custom extension. Please explain more.